# Get scope of custom directive's controller in Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I am trying to **access scope** of the controller attached with ****my custom angular directive**** when **testing in jasmine**.

```
app.directive('MyDirective', function(){
return {
         template:...,
         scope:...,
         controller: function($scope){
                $scope.clickMe = function() {
                    ....
                  };
            $scope.message = "";
         }
 }
```

I wanna write a test in jasmine to verify if the clickMe method is defined or not.

```
 it('should have 3 methods', function() {
    expect(dscope).not.toBe(null);
    expect(scope).not.toBe(null);
    expect(angular.isFunction(dscope.clickMe)).toBe(true);
    expect(dscope.message).toBe(true); }
```

In beforeEach() I declared the scope and dscope variables as follow:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(  $rootScope, $compile){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();      

    element = angular.element("<div my-directive></div>");

    //bind the empty scope into the directive
    $compile(element)(scope);

    //access to internal directive scope of our element
    dscope = element.scope();  }));
```

But when I run the test, I get "**expect false to be true."*** and expect undefined to be not null for scope.message

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using Angular 1.2+, you have to use...

```js
dscope = element.isolateScope();
```

instead of...

```js
dscope = element.scope();
```

to access isolated scopes. I can't tell if your scope is isolated because you omitted the scope declaration of your directive in the question, but I'd imagine thats whats happening here.

See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5274) issue on Github for an explanation of the difference between .scope() and .isolateScope()

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was getting mad with all the examples that wouldn't work !!

Comment: Thanks for the question & answer :)